# How can I blink LEDs with a MOSFET in response to music?

Tags: led, mosfet, audio, lithium-ion, music

I am trying to blink LEDs by music. I've done this circuit no problem:

[image: Using a TIP31]

Now wish to accomplish the same thing using an N-channel MOSFET. I tried this circuit, and got no blinks.

[image: Mosfet]

Also no success with this circuit (connecting gate to audio instead of to source):

[image]

I did not use a resistor. I know the LEDs are not blown because they work if I hook up the battery directly.

[Here's the MOSFET I am using,](http://datasheet.eeworld.com.cn/pdf/INTERSIL/20904_RFD7N10LE.pdf) with a li-ion battery.

What am I doing wrong? How can I drive LEDs with a MOSFET in response to music? Looking for simplest method.

Comment: What are you using as your audio voltage level? The threshold for turning on a MOSFET is higher than for turning on a BJT. Use resistors and more importantly learn why putting a resistor in series with an LED is important. Also learn why it's important not to parallel LEDs if they haven't got in built resistors.

Comment: The reason you didn't blow your LEDs is because the internal resistance of the 9V battery is high enough that it cannot source enough current to damage the LEDs, and you maximum current is also limited by the beta of the transistor. If you did that with a DC power supply, and with a FET like you plan, your will destroy your LEDs in a hurry.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I still wouldn't hook up a 9v battery directly to an LED though!

Comment: Note: If you websearch "color organ schematic", you will find many circuits for music-controlled lights. Adding "LED" might be a good idea in your case. Typically, these use filters to separate frequency ranges into different colors, to make the output more interesting. To "blink in time to the music" you would probably want to respond only to the bass (lowest frequencies) part of the signal, especially for today's heavily-compressed pop music.

Comment: @Andyaka Headphone output of an mp3 player. I cannot find anyplace why i should not parallel LEDs without built-in resistors, but i have found schematics showing LEDs paralleled with a single external resistor. Are they wrong?

Comment: @ConnorWolf i'm not using a 9V battery, i'm using a single 18650 li-ion battery. Why didn't it blow the LEDs when connected directly?

Comment: @keshlam thx, i know about the filtering stuff, but atm just trying to get my basic circuit working with a mosfet.

Comment: If you're using a single 18650 battery, you probably don't have enough voltage to damage anything. Those are 3.6V nominal, and you'll be losing a few hundred millivolts in the transistor.

Comment: @ConnorWolf At full charge, li-ions are 4.2V. Isn't the damage risk dependent on the specs of the LED i'm using? thx.

Comment: Yes, a LED with a low forward voltage would be more likely to be damaged. Li Ions are 4.2V at full charge, but their average voltage is 3.6V.

Answer (score 11):

The gate voltage at which a MOSFET turns on is significantly higher than the base voltage at which a BJT turns on. While for all silicon transistors this is around 0.65V, MOSFETs vary considerably, but typical values are around 3V to 6V.

So, you need to increase the source to gate voltage, \$V_{GS}\$. You could:

1. play louder music
2. put the source at a negative voltage
3. DC bias the music to a higher voltage
4. amplify the music

Here's an example of option 3, adding DC bias to the music:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fADrqO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 and R4 form a [voltage divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) which sets the DC bias. C1 blocks the DC so you don't damage the audio source. Another way to view it: C1 plus R3 and R4 form a [high-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter). This is called [capacitive coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling).

You will need to adjust the ratio of R3 and R4 to get the response you want. You might use a potentiometer. If R4 is too small and R3 is too large, then the DC bias will be too high and M1 will always be on. If R4 is too large and R3 too small, then the DC bias will be too low, and M1 will always be off (the problem you have now).

The ratio of R3 and R4 sets the DC bias, but the components aren't too critical. The input impedance is approximately R3 and R4 in parallel: \$1/(1/R_3+1/R_4)\$. You don't want this too low, or your audio source may not be able to supply enough current. Typical input impedance for line-level audio circuits is around \$10k\Omega\$ or higher.

If the resistors become too large then they stop being an accurate voltage divider, but the bias current into the gate of a MOSFET is essentially zero. Thus, the resistors could be pretty large (probably into the megaohm range).

Finally you don't want to filter out all the audio, so the cutoff frequency given by \$f_c = 1/(2\pi RC)\$, where \$R\$ is R3 and R4 in parallel as above in calculating the input impedance. Fortunately in this application some loss of lower frequencies won't be too much of a problem since no one will be listening to the result.

Comment: this is super-helpful! i guess i have to do the math to determine the HPF cutoff freq, so i don't filter out the music, right? Also, to simplify, could i eliminate R4 and just adjust R3 until i get the response i want? thx! Is it true that BJTs are tripped by current, and MOSFETs by voltage?

Comment: is there a way to ensure this will not affect the same audio going to a power amplifier? thx!

Comment: why does this falstad simulator work without any cap or resistors?
http://bit.ly/1neF8P8

Comment: @JohnyRadio - You cannot eliminate R4 - the R4||R3 network is what sets the DC operating point - it's absolutely critical. The reason the falstad simulator works is because it's a *simulator* - it ignores pretty much all the realities of actual circuits, and just simulates ideal components.

Comment: Phil, your solution worked great. I noticed it also works with a 100K pot (instead of the 20K pot you suggested)-- what are the max/min limits for the resistance between V+ and V-? Also, worked with a much larger cap on the input-- what are the min/max limits for the cap?  

@ConnorWolf "because it's a simulation" doesn't really answer the question. If it "simulates behavior of ideal components", then are you saying Phil's solution is based on non-ideal behavior?

Comment: or rather, @ConnorWolf, are you saying that if my real mosfet behaved in it's ideal way, then the circuit would work without the bias voltage? 

It sounds like, from Phil's explanation, even an ideal mosfet has a higher turn-on voltage than a BJT, and that's why the bias V is needed. Therefor, the simulator is failing not because it is displaying ideal component behavior (as you stated), but because it's NOT displaying ideal component behavior.

Comment: @JohnyRadio - I looked more closely. It turns out it's because the input signal you're using is -5V - +5V. Double-click on the oscillator, set the voltage to "1", and it does nothing, as would be expected.

Comment: @ConnorWolf many thanks, i figured the most likely explanation was MY mistake! thx!

Comment: @PhilFrost - Did you mean to respond to @JohnyRadio?

Comment: @JohnyRadio see edits.